# Storing and retrieving meta-information in R

Tags: r

I am reading a csv file that contains data related to time (which comprised of days, hours, and mins) for different activities. For example, there are five different activities: a,b,c,d, and e. I am reading data of each activity from csv file and storing it in a matrix that has three columns (for days, hours, and mins). Every activity has seperate matrix to store its related data because at the end of program I want to calculate the average time of each activity.

My Approach:
I created five matrix (because there are 5 activities) having three columns (to store days, hours, and mins data). Reading data from csv file and trying to save in right matrix (depending upon the activity).

Problem:
I face problem in managing the meta-information about the matrices. I didn't find any data structure in R, which helps in saving and retrieving the matrix information.

My approach might be wrong. If anyone has better suggestion or know how to store meta-information about the matrices. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Here is the data:

```
Activity     Duration
Variant 1   25 days, 11 hours
Variant 2   19 days, 10 hours
Variant 3   47 days, 16 hours
Variant 4   4 days, 11 hours
Variant 5   116 days, 4 hours
Variant 5   153 days, 16 hours
Variant 5   39 days, 4 hours
Variant 3   22 days, 17 hours
Variant 2   254 days, 21 hours
Variant 1   154 days, 19 mins
Variant 1   79 days, 7 hours
Variant 2   99 days, 2 hours
Variant 4   73 days, 23 hours
Variant 4   4 days, 15 hours
```

Comment: Which are the "meta-information" you want to save? Please, give us a reproducible example. There are many  ways to store meta data for an R object (you can set attributes, create a list, define a new class, ...).

Comment: Can you share example data. E.g. the first few rows of one or two csv files? Also look into `read.table`, `read.csv` and maybe a Matrix is not the best datastructure here, a `data.frame` is the more usual datasctruture here. Also to calculate mean times, convert to `POSIXct` instead of saving hours, minutes and seconds seperately.

Comment: @snaut Here is the data: